# How to correctly handcraft DNS packets with gopacket?

Tags: go, dns, wireshark, gopacket

I'm trying to send hand-crafted DNS packets with gopacket.

Here is my code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net"

    "github.com/google/gopacket"
    "github.com/google/gopacket/layers"
    "github.com/google/gopacket/pcap"
)

func main() {
    handle, err := pcap.OpenLive("lo", 1500, false, pcap.BlockForever)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Create ethernet layer
    eth := layers.Ethernet{
        SrcMAC:       net.HardwareAddr{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
        DstMAC:       net.HardwareAddr{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
        EthernetType: layers.EthernetTypeIPv4,
    }

    // Create ip layer
    ip := layers.IPv4{
        Version:  4,
        TTL:      64,
        SrcIP:    net.IP{1, 3, 3, 7},
        DstIP:    net.IP{127, 0, 0, 1},
        Protocol: layers.IPProtocolUDP,
    }

    // Create udp layer
    udp := layers.UDP{
        SrcPort: 62003,
        DstPort: 9000,
    }
    udp.SetNetworkLayerForChecksum(&ip)

    qst := layers.DNSQuestion{
        Name:  []byte{'w', 'w', 'w', '.', 'g', 'o', 'o', 'g', 'l', 'e', '.', 'c', 'o', 'm', '.'},
        Type:  layers.DNSTypeCNAME,
        Class: layers.DNSClassIN,
    }

    dns := layers.DNS{
        BaseLayer:    layers.BaseLayer{},
        ID:           0,
        QR:           true,
        OpCode:       0,
        AA:           false,
        TC:           false,
        RD:           true,
        RA:           true,
        Z:            0,
        ResponseCode: 0,
        QDCount:      1,
        ANCount:      1,
        NSCount:      0,
        ARCount:      0,
        Questions:    []layers.DNSQuestion{qst},
    }

    buffer := gopacket.NewSerializeBuffer()
    options := gopacket.SerializeOptions{
        ComputeChecksums: true,
        FixLengths:       true,
    }

    if err = gopacket.SerializeLayers(buffer, options,
        &eth,
        &ip,
        &udp,
        &dns,
    ); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    outgoingPacket := buffer.Bytes()

    if err = handle.WritePacketData(outgoingPacket); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

There is no issue and I correctly see the UDP packet going over the wire, however, when I capture it with Wireshark, it is labelled as "UDP" in the "protocol" column, but if I try `host www.google.com`, the captured packets are labelled as "DNS". So I guess I'm sending malformed packets, but I can't find what I'm missing.

[image: My packet captured with Wireshark has the wrong label in protocol section]

I have already checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59985676/sending-udp-packets-to-127-0-0-1-with-gopacket), but it didn't solve my issue.

Comment: "I'm trying to send hand-crafted DNS packets with gopacket." why? What is wrong in using the very good relevant DNS library for Go? For one thing you put "ANcount =1 " but then there is no data for the answer... Also DNS is normally to port 53 if using other ports a dissector may not know about it (your screenshot shows src port = 62003, dst port = 9000).

Comment: I know there is already a package, but I just want to try and explore other things ! And thank you for the suggestion about the port, it seems that it was the issue with Wireshark ! Feel free to officially answer to the question I'll mark it as the solution. Thanks !

Comment: "but I just want to try and explore other things" That is an honourable goal, but in case of future problems, you can use that tactic: do the packet using an high level library, save the PCAP of what happens on the network, and then try to redo it with your lower level libraries, but that way you have a working point of comparison.

Comment: That's noted, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be on Wireshark side, I tried your code and it shows up as DNS if you either:

1. use a standard port for DNS (53)

```
 udp := layers.UDP{
        SrcPort: 62003,
        DstPort: 53, // < --- changed here
 }
```

2. Right-click on entry and choose `Decode As` and change UDP port 9000 and set `Current` as `DNS`

Answer (score 0):

Try to define real MAC addresses (`eth.SrcMAC` and `eth.DstMAC`).

Also you should try crafting a question like this:

```golang
qst := layers.DNSQuestion{
    Name: []byte("www.google.com") // without the last dot
    Type:  layers.DNSTypeA,
    Class: layers.DNSClassIN,
}

dns := layers.DNS{
    RD:        true, // enable recursion (should be just enough)
    Questions: []layers.DNSQuestion{qst},
}
```